# How to define calling a state machine from an API gateway in AWS SAM syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions, aws-sam

I am trying to figure out the correct definition for my aws sam template for calling a state machine from an api proxy request. Can this be done using AWS::Serverless::Api and a swagger definition? I have this call now that goes to a lambda and Id like to replace it with my state machine

```
paths:
  "/{userUd}":
  any:
    x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
    httpMethod: POST
    type: aws_proxy
    uri:
        Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${userFunction.Arn}/invocations
    responses: {}
```

Or must I use the RestAPI gateway model? And if so an example would be amazing as I am having difficulty finding any.